# Killing a Brauer class by a flat projective morphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, brauer-groups, torsors

Let $X$ be a Noetherian scheme and $\beta \in H^2(X, \mathbb{G}_m)$ that is the image of some $\alpha \in H^1(X, \mathrm{PGL}_{n + 1})$ for some $n \ge 0$, so $\beta$ is a class in the Brauer group of $X$. Apparently, there is a projective, flat, surjective scheme morphism $\pi\colon Y \rightarrow X$ with $\pi^*(\beta) = 0$ in $H^2(Y, \mathbb{G}_m)$. This is claimed in Theorem 3.6 of Edidin, Hassett, Kresch, Vistoli "Brauer groups and quotient stacks," https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9905049 (which seems important for the overall goals of that paper).

My question is: how does one construct such a $Y$? I would be very grateful for any clarifying comments about this.

In fact, in Remark 3.9 the authors give an indication of the proof for their assertion: $Y$ is just the famous Brauer-Severi scheme of $\alpha$, the twist of $\mathbb{P}^n_X$ determined by $\alpha$ using the isomorphism $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{P}^n) = \mathrm{PGL}_{n + 1}$. I cannot see why this $Y$ works, and let me explain my doubts with the following example (which is a priori not a counterexample to their claim because the authors want to kill the Brauer class, not a $\mathrm{PGL}_{n + 1}$-torsor).

Suppose that $X = \mathrm{Spec}(k)$ for a field $k$ and let $Z \rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}(k)$ be the $\mathrm{PGL}_{n + 1}$-torsor corresponding to $\alpha$. I claim that the base change $Z_Y$ is not a trivial torsor if $\alpha$ is nontrivial: indeed, any $k$-morphism $Y \rightarrow Z$ must be constant because $Y$ is projective and $Z$ is affine. What is happening in this example is that Severi-Brauer schemes over a field are trivial as soon as they have a section, but this is no longer true over arbitrary bases such as $Y$ in the present example, so base change to $Y$ does not trivialize the Severi-Brauer scheme $Y$ (nor the torsor $Z$).

Comment: A Brauer-Severi scheme with a section has a trivial Brauer class.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Could you explain how one argues this triviality? A short comment would suffice, and posting it as an answer to the question would be most appreciated. (I apologize in case I am missing something obvious, but I would like to understand the difference from the situation with $\mathrm{PGL}_n$-torsors that appeared to be subtle as I mentioned in the question.)

Comment: I'd be happy to, but I really don't like to interact with anonymous users, so could you please send me a private email at <angelo dot vistoli at sns dot it> telling me who you are? Thanks.